# Php Twitter Post Image

Tags: php, twitter

I try to post Media on Twitter with using php. I can post tweet but image is not seen. Could you help me?

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');
/** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
    'consumer_key' => "",
    'consumer_secret' => ""
);

$media_id = '847072976486858753';
$url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$requestMethod = 'POST';
$response = $twitter->setPostfields(
    array('status' => 'Test Tweet', 'media_ids' => $media_id)
)->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good, I assume the $media_id you're using is valid? Here's some code to handle the image upload first, then post the tweet.

```
// send image to Twitter first
$url = 'https://upload.twitter.com/1.1/media/upload.json';
$requestMethod = 'POST';

$image = 'full/path/to/image.jpg';

$postfields = array(
  'media' => base64_encode(file_get_contents($image))
);

$response = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
  ->setPostfields($postfields)
  ->performRequest();

// get the media_id from the API return
$media_id = json_decode($response)->media_id;

// then send the Tweet along with the media ID
$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
$requestMethod = 'POST';

$postfields = array(
  'status' => 'My amazing tweet'
  'media_ids' => $media_id,
);

$response = $twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
  ->setPostfields($postfields)
  ->performRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the image handling portion.

```
$url_media = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update_with_media.json";
$requestMethod = "POST";

$tweetmsg = $_POST['post_description'];
$twimg = $_FILES['pictureFile']['tmp_name'];

    $postfields = array(
        'status' => $tweetmsg,
        'media[]' => '@' . $twimg
    );
    try {
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        $twitter->buildOauth($url_media, $requestMethod)
                ->setPostfields($postfields)
                ->performRequest();

        echo "You just tweeted with an image";
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From 5 years ago a lot of things changed with Twitter APIs.. in 2022 I personally use https://github.com/dg/twitter-php ( https://phpfashion.com/twitter-for-php ) **(just one bug about images fixable with this version)**:

`composer.json`

```json
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "git@github.com:peterjaap/twitter-php.git"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "dg/twitter-php": "dev-patch-1"
    }
}
```

`test.php`

```php
<?php

require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use DG\Twitter\Twitter;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', '...your-code-here');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', '...your-code-here');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', '...your-code-here');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', '...your-code-here');

$twitter = new Twitter(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

// optional image/s
$image = "./tempfile.jpg";
file_put_contents($image, fopen("https://live.staticflickr.com/5095/5446290949_73ed733c0d_c.jpg", 'r'));

try {
    $tweet = $twitter->send('this is my cool tweet', array($image)); // you can add $imagePath or array of image paths as second argument
    unlink($image);
} catch (DG\Twitter\TwitterException $e) {
    echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

don't forget to add write permission to your twitter app ( https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/dashboard )

[image: twitter write permission]